# How to extract repeated characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract those phonemes that reoccur in words. I've phonemic transcriptions of words such as these:

```
x <- c("saɪəns", "ɪvɒlvd", "ˌʌndəstænd", "skɑːb(ə)rə", "pəteɪtəʊ", "dɪskraɪbd")
```

Using `gsub` and backreference, I can do this:

```
gsub(".*(.).*\\1.*", "\\1", x, perl = T)
[1] "s" "v" "d" "ə" "t" "ɪ"
```

However the result is incomplete, as only *one* repeated letter is outputted; the complete result would be:

```
[1] "s" "v" "nd" "ə" "ət" "dɪ"
```

I've tried it with multiple backreference but this outputs the entire strings:

```
gsub(".*(.).*\\1.*(.).*\\2", "\\1\\2", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "saɪəns"     "ɪvɒlvd"     "ˌʌndəstænd" "skɑːb(ə)rə" "pəteɪtəʊ"   "dɪskraɪbd"
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
x <- c("saɪəns", "ɪvɒlvd", "ˌʌndəstænd", "skɑːb(ə)rə", "pəteɪtəʊ", "dɪskraɪbdɪ")
sapply(str_extract_all(x, "(.)(?=.*\\1)"), function(z) paste(unique(z), collapse=""))
# => [1] "s"  "v"  "nd" "ə"  "ət" "dɪ"
```

See [an online R demo](https://ideone.com/bDJ2FF).

The `(.)(?=.*\1)` regex finds all chars that are followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, until the same char. The `stringr::str_extract_all` extracts all occurrences (so the total amount of the same char is *n*-1). Since this results in duplicates, the `uniq` function must be applied to each character vector when `collapse`ing.

Answer (score 2):

tabulate letter frequency and return those appearing more than once?

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(s){ f <- table(s); paste0(names(f[f>1]), collapse = '') })
# [1] "s"  "v"  "dn" "ə"  "ət" "dɪ"
```

An empty string will be returned in case of no repeated characters:

```
x <- c('abb', 'ab')
sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(s){ f <- table(s); paste0(names(f[f>1]), collapse = '') })
# [1] "b" ""
```